# Library for validating phone number format

Tags: ios

In Java/Android there a library for validating international phone numbers https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/

Is there any similar library for iOS/Objective-C.

Comment: They appear to have a C++ version in that very library; why not just use it?

Comment: You could always just port the library you linked to. It's like 12 code files and you probably don't need all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it has actually the objective-c port: https://github.com/me2day/libPhoneNumber-iOS