# Validate both Local (Indian) and international mobile number validation

Tags: ios

Hi in my app user has option to send sms. From this I need to show only the contact which has valid mobile number. That mobile number can be local or any country mobile number. How to validate the mobile number for all country. Please show a right path to do this..

Now I am using this regular expression : **^+[1-9]{1}[0-9]{10}$** but this not validate **+9597038056** this kind of numbers...

Thanks in advance for all valuable answers.....

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18036771/library-for-validating-phone-number-format?rq=1

Comment: @rmaddy: I can't get how to use this.

Comment: @rmaddy: Great answer thank you... But here we need to set default country code that is the problem. Any way to set dynamic country code.